# DocumentDB Query to find created date

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I want to retrieve the documents with only documentID and document Created DateTime details. I am able to get the DocumentID by following query but how can we get the Document created datetime.

```
select c.id from c
```

However, along with id I need to get the document created date also

Any help on this appreciated !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am able to get the DocumentID by following query but how can we get
>   the Document created datetime.

From this official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-resources#system-vs-user-defined-resources) , the automatically generated properties of the document when it is created consists only of the following: `_rid,_etag,_ts,_self,id.`

`_ts` represents last updated timestamp of the resource, so if this document has not been updated, then this time is the `createTime`. You could query it via `Select  c.id,c._ts from c`.

So, maybe you need to log `createTime` by yourself when you create documents so that you could query the `createTime` later.

Hope it helps you.

---

The `id` , `_ts` or other custom properties like `DocumentReadingCreatedDate` are all properties in the document which is not divided into system details or non-system details. Just some of the properties I mentioned above are the fields that cosmosdb will automatically generate for you.

So you just need to use sql : `select c._ts from c` to find the newest update time of this document. You could get a `long` type data such as `1520216339` ,then you could convert it into datetime format such as `Sun Jan 18 22:16:56 CST 1970` in your program.

If your documents have been updated and you must get the create time of the document, you can't use `_ts` field. You could only use your custom field `DocumentReadingCreatedDate`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. However, can you explain how can i get the date ? Actually I don't want to open the document to get any details from document.

Comment: @Rohit Sorry ,what's meaning of don't want to open the document?

Comment: Means we will play only with documentID, created date time etc. Like system details. Though we are having field as 'DocumentReadingCreatedDate' in the document.

Comment: @Rohit Please see my additional answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. query is working fine.. just one question the timestamp provided by _ts it doesn't contain so how can i get date from it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166475/discussion-between-rohit-and-jay-gong).

Comment: @Rohit Sorry, it seems we're in the different timezones.  You could convert the _ts value to datetime format in your program. I'm not sure which language you're using , such as in java code:  Date now = new Date(1520216339L);

Answer (score 1):

The _ts is a Unix Timestamp value.

You need to convert it. The following C# sample will do it.

```
 private static DateTime UnixTimeStampToDateTime(long unixTimeStamp) 
{
   System.DateTime dtDateTime = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
   dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddMilliseconds(unixTimeStamp);
   return dtDateTime;
}
```

Or you can create a UFD that you can use in your query, The following is one that will work

```
function epochToDate (ts) {
  return new Date(ts*1000);
}
```

You would use it as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE udf.epochToDate(c._ts) == ....
```

Comment: C# calculation needs to be `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddMilliseconds(_ts * 1000)`